# Postgres dump: pg_catalog.setval

Tags: postgresql

Does anyone know what pg_catalog.setval does?

I just did a dump off a PostgreSQL database and got lots of lines with that in it. Not sure what it's for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might want to check the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html):

> setval(regclass, bigint)  bigint  Set
>   sequence's current value

Example usage:;

```
# create sequence x;
CREATE SEQUENCE

# select nextval('x');
 nextval
---------
       1
(1 row)

# select nextval('x');
 nextval
---------
       2
(1 row)

# select nextval('x');
 nextval
---------
       3
(1 row)

# select setval('x', 10000);
 setval
--------
  10000
(1 row)

# select nextval('x');
 nextval
---------
   10001
(1 row)

# select nextval('x');
 nextval
---------
   10002
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks, tried googling this and didn't come up with anything.